# How to open a terminal and close it again (when script ends)?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to open a terminal, eg. using `gnome-terminal` and then have it exit(killed) later either programaticly or just by itself when script ends ?

I want to use this for a test setup in where I need to run some different things - then having to manual close the different terminals is not so nice. Having each program in its own terminal is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this inside your script file, add this to the end of your file. This will send a `SIGKILL` signal to the script's parent process, so if there is one bash linked to the terminal, this will kill the terminal, but if there's more than one bash linked to the terminal, it won't kill the terminal.

```
kill -9 $PPID
```

Or you can run your script this way, and the terminal will be closed after the script is finished:

```
./your_script.sh && exit
```

Comment: ... it shouldn't generally be necessary to resort to `-9` (`SIGKILL`) - plain `kill` (`SIGHUP`) should be sufficient

Comment: What I want is to kill the childs when parent is done/gets stopped. Imagine starting 20 terminals that don't exit (they are running a program in each) by themselves and having to manual close each one when test is done..